# Finding the normal between a cylinder and a triangle

Tags: math, geometry, collision

I have a pretty rudimentary physics engine in the game I'm working on, between moving, cylindrical characters, and static meshes made of triangles. The intended behavior is for characters to slide across surfaces, and in most cases, it works fine. But the engine doesn't discriminate between a head-on collision and a glancing collision.

I'm not entirely sure what information I could give that would be helpful. I'm looking for a mathematical solution, at any rate, a method to determine the 'angle of contact' between an arbitrary cylinder and triangle. My instincts, or whatever, tell me that I need to find the point of contact between the triangle and the cylinder, then determine whether that point is within the triangle (Using the triangle's regular normal) or along one of its edges (Using the angle between the point of contact and some point on the cylinder, I'm not sure which.), but I'm sure there's a better solution.

[image]

As requested, here's a couple of examples. In this first image, a cylinder travels downwards towards a triangle (In this example, the triangle is vertical, simplified to a line.) I project the velocity vector onto the plane of the triangle, using the formula `Vf = V - N * (dot(V,N))`. This is the intended behavior for this type of collision.

[image]

In this image, the cylinder's axis is parallel with the normal of the triangle. Under the current implementation, Vf is still determined using the triangle's natural normal, which would cause the cylinder to begin moving vertically. Under intended behavior, N would be perpendicular to the colliding edge of the triangle.

But these are just the two extremes of collision. There are going to be a bunch of in-betweens, so I need a more arbitrary solution.

[image]

This is my attempt at a more 3D example. I apologize for the poor perspective. The bottom-most vertex in this triangle is closer to the 'camera'. The point of collision between the cylinder and the triangle is marked by the red X. Under intended behavior, if the cylinder was moving directly away from the camera, it would slide to the left, along the length of the triangle's edge. No vertical movement would be imparted, as the point of contact is along the cylinder's, uh, tube section, rather than the caps.

Under current behavior, the triangle's normal is used. The cylinder would be pushed upwards, as though sliding across the face of the triangle, while doing little to prevent movement into the triangle.

I understand that this is a difficult request, so I appreciate the suggestions made to help refine my question.

Comment: perhaps provide an illustration, or an example situation and what the expected answer should be

Comment: if you could formulate it as a math problem (ie, find a way to specify the triangle and cylinder using coordinates (maybe of the vertices and the radii and position, etc.) you could ask it on the math stack exchange

Comment: I have inserted the images, please check for correctness.

Comment: I do not yet understand the problem. A cylinder is 3-D and a triangle is 2-D, how do these collide? In your examples, the problem reduces to 2-D and the cylinder is shown as a circle. Can you show an example of a more general situation. (I understand that drawing a 3-D picture might be difficult :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably an edge collision detector. In rigid body collision systems, there are usually two types of collisions: surface collisions (for colliding with things that have a regular surface normal, where the reaction normal can be computed easily, as you pointed out, by processing A velocity vs B surface normal), and edge collisions (where the A body hits the edge of B body, be it box, triangle or anything else). In this case, the matter is more complicated, because, obviously, edge is *not* a surface, and thus you *can't* calculate it's normal at all. Usually, it's approximated one way or another - you can for example assume that, for triangle mesh, the edge normal is the average between normals of the two edge triangle's. There are also other methods to deal with it, some discussed here:

https://code.google.com/p/bullet/downloads/detail?name=CEDEC2011_ErwinCoumans.pdf&can=2&q=

Usually, there's an edge processing threshold value, if a collision occurred in the radius of this value, it's considered an edge collision, and processed differently.

See the examples here:
http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2012/10/31/2d-polygonal-collision-detection-and-internal-edges/

Googling "internal edge collision" and learning about rigid body collisions/dynamics in general will help you understand and solve this problem by yourself.